# OmniORB C++ client. Cannot connect to two different servers

Tags: c++, corba, omniorb

We are developing a C++ CORBA client using the omniORB libraries.

Our application needs to connect to two different servers, each hosted on a different machine. To achieve this we use two `CORBA::ORB_ptr` variables. What is funny is that our programs appear to work correctly when we connect to one server no matter which, but when one `ORB_ptr` is active then attempting to connect to the second gives us a `CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound` exception.

Comment: Good lord! Are there people still doing CORBA? Does OmniOrb keep log files? Have you tried any other orbs such as ACE/TAO?

Comment: Or try TAOX11, the C++11 language mapping will save you a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to ORB variables to connect to two servers, you need two object references, one for each server, that can be done using one ORB. For both servers you have to retrieve the object reference from for example the naming service, narrow them to the correct type, and you can use them.

Check a CORBA book, for example see http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply or see the examples/tests that distributions ship.

Comment: As far as I know, you need the ORB_ptr object in order to connect to the server, using the CORBA::ORB_init() function. Using this you get a reference to the server's root naming context, then you resolve the actual name which gives you the real server object that provides the functionality you want. So to get data from two servers you need to start with two OBR_ptr variables and end up with two service pointers. The thing is that if one conects then the other fails no matter which conects first.

Comment: It is correct you need a ORB_ptr first. But, using this one ORB_ptr you can call the naming service multiple times, you get a different object reference back on each call. Does you server correct register itself in the naming service? Each instance has to register itself using a different name.

Comment: There must be some kind of misunderstanding, when I refer to two different servers, I mean different hosts and different ports. I am not talking about two services provided by the same CORBA server.

Comment: Yes, that is also what I mean. Your client process needs only a single ORB, that can connect to both servers without problems.